# Python search string for two numbers, assign to variables

Tags: python

I have the following string a part of a file with lines with the same format.

```
CONST robtarget robttarget1:=[[-42277.480909368,-4997.36320197,2332.380745999],[0.347787091,-0.799426288,0.217080241,0.439133144],[0,0,0,0],[-35700.0,180.0,2200.000095367,0,9E9,9E9]];
```

I need to access two specific numbers and preform math on them.  -35700.0 and 180.0.

I am struggling with getting those specific values and assign them to variables.

Comment: So far just open the file, loop through each line and print it out.

Comment: I am trying to cut the first text off, then I can access a list of lists.

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of the part of the lines that are not the value and use `eval` to get the rest as a python variable.

The following line will break your string at the '=' character using `split` (so you will get 2 strings). 
It will then get the second part of your string (the one which starts after the '='), remove the final ';' character and use `eval` to interpret the whole thing:

```
result = eval(s.split('=')[1][:-1])
```

Now you'll get a list of lists that you can extract your numbers from easily

Comment: Using [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) would be safer, it protects against malicious strings being evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string by the "=" and then use the ast module to convert the string list to a python list object and the use list indexing to fetch the required value

**EX:**

```
import ast
A = "CONST robtarget robttarget1:=[[-42277.480909368,-4997.36320197,2332.380745999],[0.347787091,-0.799426288,0.217080241,0.439133144],[0,0,0,0],[-35700.0,180.0,2200.000095367,0,9E9,9E9]];"
A = A.split("=")[1].replace(";", "")   #Remove any non python string.
A = ast.literal_eval(A)    #Convert string object to list object
print A[-1][0:2]           # I have used slice to fetch the required value
```

**Output:**

```
[-35700.0, 180.0]
```